Unable to start firefox geckodriver in Symfony Panther using Ubuntu linux cronjob unless user is logged in
I have some web scraping and screeshotting using Symphony Panther. That worked flawlessly on my dev machine. With some adaptions I made it work on a Ubuntu 22 server also. Now I wanted to do it as a cron job.
I added...
/usr/bin/php /opt/mybot/mybot.php >> /var/log/mybot/cron.log 2>&1

...as a cron job. While normale scraping worked fine, as soon as I want to create a firefox screenshot I get an exception
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not start firefox. Exit code: 1 (General error). Error output: /system.slice/cron.service is not a snap croup
However as long as I am logged into that machine via SSH (without doing anything else) the cron job runs fine without any exception. That puzzles me a bit (and makes it hard to debug to be fair).
Is there something I can do, so that it works unattended?

Why do you need Composer to run any Cronjob?

I don't, I just wrap everything php as composer scripts; updated question to reflect it is not about composer.

The error "/system.slice/cron.service is not a snap cgroup" means that both the Firefox browser and the cron service are not in the same slick group and hence, can't interact. You can see more about it here;
you can see more about the possible options you have here
For me, I was able to get it to work using sudo with corn!
